# How cut and paste in the line in Vim editor?

Tags: vim

I'm tring to copy `c = getchar()` to `c! ^ =EOF`.

I tried `shift+v & p`, the code will appear right above the line, not in the line.

What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar()
    while (c != EOF {
        putchar(c);
    }
}



#include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
        int c;

        while (c = getchar()!= EOF) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place your cursor on the line you want to yank.
2. If you are not on the `c`, hit `^`.
3. Cut until the end of line with `d$`.
4. Move to where you want to put. With `/c`, for example.
5. Enter visual mode and put, with `vlp`.

Answer (score 2):

When you yank the `c = getchar()` *line*, the register is in *linewise mode*, so any pastes will also create a new line. My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has mappings like `gcp` that force e.g. a *characterwise* paste. With that, you can insert the line after the `while(` statement, and have it stay in the same line.

But actually, you probably want to replace the `c` after the `while(` with the yanked text. For that, another of my plugins, the [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) comes handy. With it, you can either visually select the `c` or address it through a motion `l`, and use the plugin's `gr` mapping to replace the covered text with the register contents (again, sticking to the same line, so you only have to deal with the superfluous indent).

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this kind of work with operations in movements over the same line with <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd>. So I would do:

```
:20
```

to go to the line of `c = getchar()!= EOF`

```
fcdf)
```

to put cursor in first `c` letter and cut until next `)` character.

```
:7
```

go to seventh line, and

```
f(p
```

to go to first `(` character and paste.